# Delphi - What Structure allows for SAVING inverted index type of information?

Tags: delphi, data-structures, collections

Delphi XE6.  Looking to implemented a limited style of search, specifically an edit field for the user to enter a business name which would get looked up.  I need to allow the user to enter multiple words, or part of multiple words.  For Example, on a business "First Bank of Kansas", user should be able to enter "Fir Kan", and it should return a match.  This means an inverted index type of structure.  I have some type of list of each unique word, then a (document ID, primary Key ID, etc, which is an integer).  I am struggling with WHAT type of structure to make this...  I have approximately 250,000 business names, which have 43,500 unique words. Word count will vary from 1 occurrence of a word to several thousand (company, corporation, etc) I have some requirements...

1).  Assume the user enters BAN. I need to find ALL words that start with BAN.  I need to return BANK, BANKER, etc...  This means that whatever structure I use, I have to be able to find BAN and then move to the next alphabetic entry... and keep moving to the next until I find a value that does NOT start with BAN.  This eliminates any type of HASH structure, correct?

2).  I obviously want this to be fast.  HASH is the fastest, but I can't use this, correct?  See requirement 1.

3).  Each entry in this structure needs to be able to hold a list of integers.  If I end up going with a LinkedList, then each element has to hold a list of Integers.

4).  I need to be able to save and load this structure.  I don't want to have to build it each time I use it.

Whatever I end up with, it appears to have to be a NESTED structure, a higher level list (LinkedList?) with each node being an Integer List.

What am I looking for?  What do commercial product use?  Outlook, etc have search capabilities.

Comment: This sounds a lot like a TComboBox with the Style of csDropDown and AutoComplete set to True.

Comment: Do you expect match if one writes `Kan Fir` for that `First Bank of Kansas` as well ? And what about case sensitivity and diacritic ?

Comment: @TLama - yes, it should match either way.  By tracking each word, I can determine which businesses contain that word (or partial word).  When I build my structure, I will convert to CAPS first.  When user is searching, I will convert to CAPS as well..  As to diacritics, all business are in the US.

Comment: Could a database be an option?

Comment: This problem has been addressed exhaustively in an old C programming book published in the 80's, maybe by PJ Plauger. It's the root of a commonly used Unix command (unfortunately I forget its name at the moment). Anybody else know what I'm referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every word is linked to a specific set of IDs, each representing a business name, right?.

I recommend using a binary tree data structure because effort for searching is normally *log(n)*, which is quite fast. Especially, if business names are changing at runtime, an AVLTree should do well, although it's quite some work to implement it by yourself. But there should be many ready-to-use units on binary trees all over the internet.

For each successful search for a word in your tree data structure, you should take their list of IDs and aggregate those grouped by the entered word they succeeded for.
As the last step you take all those aggregated lists of IDs and do an intersection.

There should only be IDs left which are fitting to all entered words. Those IDs are referencing the searched business names.

Comment: There are not as many out there as you think... LOL.  I looked at several.  Here is one that appears to be very solid, free, includes source, and supports saving/loading to streams/files.  http://sourceforge.net/projects/alcinoe/

Comment: @user1009073 Maybe this is helpful, too. It seems to be a lot shorter than Alcinoe, so it might have less overhead. [ibrtses.com/delphi/binarytree](http://www.ibrtses.com/delphi/binarytree.html)

Comment: @RH -Thank you.  I looked at that one.  The reason I did not go with it was it did not support saving/load to streams or files.  Yes, I could add it, but still....